# Add and Customize Pages permissions required for Full Control user to add Basic page to document library

Tags: document-library, content-type

I'm an admin on a modern Hub Team Site in SharePoint Online, with Full Control Permissions.  I created a Document Library and enabled content types and added the Basic Page type so I can add pages to this library.

Whenever I try to create an entry in this library from the Basic Page option, I am able to create the page by naming the file, but the following step that should open the page in design mode shows this error:

> **Web Part Error**: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions required to perform this action.

I've seen various posts from the classic experience talking about the need to create a new permission at the site level with the required permissions, but doing that and adding my user which already has Full Control doesn't fix it.

How can this be the out-of-the-box experience for page content types in a document library for a user who already has full control?? Is this a long-standing bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, often to discourage the use of classic features or due to potential security issues with scripting. You can run this on the site:

```
Set-SPOSite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages:$false
```

That will allow you to leverage these features.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I'm starting to think I've led myself down the wrong path. I'm now understanding that the Basic Page content type is for using classic web parts. I want to use a Site Page, which I understand is the modern experience for adding Apps Web Parts. I basically want a second Document Library for these pages (with specific permissions) so I can create a page just like the kind you create from the New -> Site Page dropdown when in the Site Pages library. That functionality works fine there, but when I include the Site Page content type and do the same action the editor never appears

Comment: I don't get an error for the Site Page content type, just no editor is displayed (just a blank page in the site shell for the new .aspx page with a random file name) and the browser continuously loops requests ("Waiting for...", "Processing request"). I expect this to work the same as New -> Site Page from the Site Pages library or the tool bar on the default site page. Perhaps I need to create a new question for this specific problem

Comment: Note that if I go back to the document library and find the page that was created, I can then open it and edit it